# Is there a way to get a shared spreadsheet to update without closing and reopening?

Tags: windows, microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

Using Excel 2010, I have a spreadsheet that is used by 3 different people at any one time.  But if one person has the spreadsheet open on there PC the other people can only view it as read only.  I have since shared the workbook and put the spreadsheet on a shared network drive and now they can all view the spreadsheet at the same time and edit it at the same time.

The problem is that nobody can see the changes that the other users have made unless the close out of the spreadsheet and open it up again to view the changes.  I have checked the settings of the shared workbook and on the advanced tab have tick the option that updates the information every 5 minutes but the information does not update until you close out and open the spreadsheet back up again.

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: seems that it will auto update when you save the document

Answer (score 4):

In Excel 2010, with the workbook to be shared open, select the `Review` tab and you will see the `Changes` section of the ribbon.

[image]

Click `Share Workbook` to select options. On the `Advance` tab the `Update changes` is in the middle of the window. Adjust accordingly. Remember to save changes when done.

[image]

Here are detailed instructions from Microsoft for Excel 2010; [use a shared workbook to collaborate](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/use-a-shared-workbook-to-collaborate-HP010342985.aspx?CTT=1)

Comment: Sorry we are using Microsoft Excel 2010. The spreadsheet is designed for the users to input prices for the products we sell and ship out these prices are always changing so if one user puts in the new price for the product and it doesn't update calculations will be wrong by the other users

Comment: Thanks for the additional details. You can use F9 to update calculations manually or set it to automatic in `options` from the `File` tab.

Comment: To complete CharlieRB's answer, the refresh setting is a local one and therefore needs to be updated for all users. It's not linked to the file being viewed.

Comment: What "refresh" setting are you referring to?